# What need to do after pre-generated the view

Tags: entity-framework

I've already pre-generated the view and got the .view.cs file, what should I do now to let the application using this file? or just build it and the then the application will using this one automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Just include it in your project (so that it's built with the rest of your code). That's all.